# Convert js object to hierarchic JSON structure

Tags: javascript

I have to create a JavaScript function to convert an object like the one bellow into a hierarchic JSON object.

The source is an HR employee list with it's corresponding manager.

Source Object:

```
Employee    Manager Title
Alfredo             general manager
Bergman     Alfredo senior engineer
Billy       Alfredo senior engineer
Johnson     Alfredo department manager
Angela      Johnson senior engineer
Anderson    Johnson senior engineer
Amy         Johnson department manager
Patsy       Amy     engineer
Jane        Amy     engineer
```

This is how the JSON object should look like:

```
var datasource = {
  'name': 'Alfredo',
  'title': 'general manager',
  'children': [
    { 'name': 'Bergman', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
    { 'name': 'Johnson', 'title': 'department manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Anderson', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
        { 'name': 'Amy', 'title': 'department manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Patsy', 'title': 'engineer'},
            { 'name': 'Jane', 'title': 'engineer'}
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Angela', 'title': 'senior engineer' }
      ]
    },
    { 'name': 'Billy', 'title': 'senior engineer' }
  ]
};
```

I have tried various methods unsuccessfully, but I am quite noob on JavaScript.

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: why doe sthe result has a different sorting?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a do-it-for-me service. Please show us what have *you* tried.

Comment: btw, JSON is a string representation of a javascript object.  So, it's not a *JSON structure* you are looking for but rather to convert a flat list object to a more structured/hierarchical list object.  Also, there is an implication in the hierarchy of the source list that doesn't quite match the proposed output.  As you iterate through the source, you need to have a clear understanding of what are child objects.   The placement of **Billy** makes it difficult to follow the logic exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you want it to do: Iterate the list, building a map of all the employees, then sort the employees into the right set of children by the managers name, returning only the employee(s) that have no manager.

```js
var entries = [{ name: 'Bergman', manager: 'Alfredo', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Billy', manager: 'Alfredo', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Johnson', manager: 'Alfredo', title: 'department manager' }, { name: 'Angela', manager: 'Johnson', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Anderson', manager: 'Johnson', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Amy', manager: 'Johnson', title: 'department manager' }, { name: 'Patsy', manager: 'Amy', title: 'engineer' }, { name: 'Jane', manager: 'Amy', title: 'engineer' }, { name: 'Alfredo', manager: '', title: 'general manager' }]
function build_org_chart(list) {
    var map = {}, node, managers = [], i;

    // Build the map of employees we will use later.
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        map[list[i].name] = i;
        list[i].directReports = []; // init the children
    }

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        node = list[i];
        if (node.manager != "") {

            // If the employee has a manager, find them
            var indexOfManager = map[node.manager];

            // Then add that employee to the managers children.
            list[indexOfManager].directReports.push(node);
        } else {

            // If they haven't got a manager, must be a boss.
            managers.push(node);
        }
    }

    // Return only the top bosses.
    return managers;
}

console.log(build_org_chart(entries));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop approach by using the relation of employee to manager and vice versa.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Bergman', manager: 'Alfredo', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Billy', manager: 'Alfredo', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Johnson', manager: 'Alfredo', title: 'department manager' }, { name: 'Angela', manager: 'Johnson', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Anderson', manager: 'Johnson', title: 'senior engineer' }, { name: 'Amy', manager: 'Johnson', title: 'department manager' }, { name: 'Patsy', manager: 'Amy', title: 'engineer' }, { name: 'Jane', manager: 'Amy', title: 'engineer' }, { name: 'Alfredo', manager: '', title: 'general manager' }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function ({ name, manager, title }) {
            Object.assign(o[name] = o[name] || {}, { name, title }, o[name].children && { children: o[name].children });
            o[manager] = o[manager] || { name: null, title: null };
            o[manager].children = o[manager].children || [];
            o[manager].children.push(o[name]);
        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, '');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm guessing his biggest issue is the format of the input data.